# NoClassDefFoundError while export to pdf

Tags: java, jasper-reports, itext, export-to-pdf

I am facing error at the time of export jasper report into pdf. That shows NoClassDefFoundError. I tried somany things like added recent itextPdf jar and itext jar. Then i moved those file into ext sub folder of lib. but, i have no luck can any one tell me, what was the problem?

This is my code:

```
JasperPrint jprint = (JasperPrint) JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperFileName, param, conn);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jprint, pdfFileName); //exportReportToPdf(jprint);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jprint);
```

Here my Problem:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException
```

Comment: Make sure you have the itext jar file in your classpath

Comment: i already added itext.jar

Comment: *i already added itext.jar* - which version? Your JR version seems to require the old `com.lowagie.**` iText flavor, i.e. a version before 5.0.0. Since then iText uses a `com.itextpdf.**` package hierarchy.

Comment: i am using itext 5.0.6 jar file

Comment: 5.0.6 is the wrong version. Jasper Reports uses 2.1.7, with `com.lowagie.**` packages.

Answer (score 1):

you miss the `itext.jar` in your classpath. Download and add it, so the exception will gone.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two good ways to solve this and possible similar problems:

1. Use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) to handle dependencies.
2. Copy the folder "lib" from the [Jasper Reports library](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library/resources) to your project and add all the jars from it to your build path.

Answer (score 0):

JasperReports library is using customized version of itext 2.1.7. You'll have to use this version because itext is not compatilble between versions 2.x and 5.x.